# VSCode 'Run Without Debugging' hangs

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, debugging

I've created a vanilla react app with typescript using
`npx create-react-app test --template typescript`.
Latest VSCode (1.87.2), latest Chrome (123.0.6312.59). Windows 11. Firefox is my default browser, but my launch.json intentionally specifies Chrome (I prefer Chrome's debugging facilities):

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run `npm start`, firefox starts with the site as expected. If I close the firefox page and use VSCode's `Run | Start Debugging` menu option, all works as expected. But if I use `Run | Run Without Debugging`, chrome comes up, with the correct url, but it hangs forever without getting to any of my code.

This is new behavior - all of this was working perfectly not long ago. I'm not sure when it changed, since I don't use `Run Without Debugging` all the time, but it's within the past couple of weeks.

Can anyone provide a clue as to what might be going wrong and/or how I might track this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - it appears to be a bug in the latest js debugger in vscode. Installing the nightly extension fixes the problem. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#nightly-extension